# How do I suppress this Analyzer suggestion about a strong reference

Tags: ios, llvm

I have a class method which uses a while loop to create and use NSTextStorage objects. The object or what's happening isn't really important, but essentially I need to keep a strong reference to the object before the loop ends, so that it isn't released in memory before the loop next runs.

```
NSTextStorage *strongTextStorageForLoop;
while (condition)
{
    ...
    NSTextStorage *storageObject = [[NSTextStorage alloc] init...
    ...
    strongTextStorageForLoop = nil;
    strongTextStorageForLoop = storageObject
}
```

Xcode's Static Analyzer is telling me that this variable is useless because its value is never read. That is correct but I still need it for my code to execute properly.

So I'd like to know either how to accomplish this in a cleaner way, or how to suppress the Analyzer's suggestion (without simply doing an NSLog).

Comment: This line is useless: `strongTextStorageForLoop = nil;` because on the next line `strongTextStorageForLoop` is set to another value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply do this:

```
NSTextStorage *storageObject;
while (condition)
{
    ...
    storageObject = [[NSTextStorage alloc] init...
    ...
}
```

Does this do what you need? It will keep the last object right up to the point the next one is created.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't just do that in the first place. Thanks!